# display div's in for each one by one depending on the interval times in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

Hi guys i am trying to  display my content data in div's one by one depending on interval times set for that particular content.

my requirement is i have one group that group contains multiple contents like text,image or video for example if i have added 3 contents to one group these three contents need to run one b one depending on their particular interval times i have set time for each content like 30secs,40secs,50secs
Now in my code those all 3 div's are displaying in same page and interval time also not working

Can any one help me how to solve this issue.

Here is my view page code:

```
<!--Display Dynamic Content-->
<div class="container">
    <h2>Text Content</h2>
    <?php
    if (!empty($displaycontent)) {
        foreach ($displaycontent as $content) {
            $time = $content->displaytime;
            $typeofinfo = $content->typeofinfo;
            $content = $content->details;

            $seconds = strtotime("1970-01-01 $time UTC");
            $miliseconds = $seconds * 1000;
            echo $seconds . "\n" . $miliseconds; 

        if ($typeofinfo == '2') {
                ?>
                <div id="pageContent" class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                 <?php echo $content; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php
        } elseif ($typeofinfo == '8') {
            ?>
                <div id="pageContent" class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <img src="<?=site_url('new/'.$content); ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>

            <?php
        } elseif ($typeofinfo == '6') {
            ?>
                 <div id="pageContent" class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <video width="400" controls>
                            <source src="<?=site_url('new/'.$content); ?>" type="video/mp4">
                            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                        </video>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
?> 
</div>


<script>
var inputTime=<?php echo $miliseconds;?>;
window.onload=function()
{
  setTimeout(hidePage, inputTime);

};

function hidePage()
{
    $("#pageContent").show();

}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicated IDs: **pageContent**. Change to class or add a final number like: pageContent1, pageContent2, pageContent3

The [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)  sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code once after the timer expires. Hence you need to execute the setTimeout again in order to accomplish your task.

Changing pageContent to class your js will be:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    $(".pageContent").hide();
    var timeout = $(".pageContent").first().data('timeout');
    setTimeout(hidePage, timeout, $(".pageContent"));
});

function hidePage(eles) {
    if (eles.length>0) {
        $(".pageContent").hide();
        eles.first().show();
        eles = eles.slice(1);
        var timeout = eles.first().data('timeout') || 0;
        setTimeout(hidePage, timeout, eles);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Display Dynamic Content-->
<div class="container">
    <h2>Text Content</h2>
    <div class="pageContent panel panel-default" data-timeout="<?php echo $miliseconds;?>">
        <div class="panel-body">
            content1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pageContent panel panel-default" data-timeout="<?php echo $miliseconds;?>">
        <div class="panel-body">
            content2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pageContent panel panel-default" data-timeout="<?php echo $miliseconds;?>">
        <div class="panel-body">
            content3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: added a running snippet. Let me know where is  the mistake. Thanks